# TransactionScope does not run on localhost

Tags: c#, .net, transactionscope

I am getting this error:

> Network access for Distributed Transaction Manager (MSDTC) has been
>   disabled. Please enable DTC for network access in the security
>   configuration for MSDTC using the Component Services Administrative
>   tool.

Is there a way to run [`TransactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) on localhost? I can run the thing on a server but in my local environment I get this error.  Is there some settings we need to make so that we can use a `TransactionScope`?

Comment: you shouldn't need DTC if your transaction is within a single DB - is this the case?

Comment: well i want the DTC because i use transactions to commit the saved changes...and the DTC doesnt work on Localhost but it does on Deployment Server

Comment: `TransactionScope` does not require DTC as such - it is only escalated if needed across multiple DB connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to start the service in Windows.

Start > Run. services.msc

[image]

UPDATE:

Check your Component Services too;

Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Component Services

[image]

Comment: i did that but no success are you sure that is the thing we need to set

Comment: Yeah, almost certain. I had the same problem the other week.

Comment: Hey Iain I did this and it worked...Go to Control Panel-> Administrative Tools->Component Service->Computers-> My Computer->Distributed Transaction Coordinator->Right Click on Local DTC, Select Properties->Go to Security tab->Enable the Following CheckBox: Network DTC access, Allow inbound, Allow Outbound, Allow Remote Client, Allow Remote Administration..Thanks for your Help